# Meine Beine sind lang und meine Finger sind dick

Tags: translation

I am providing an example from my German textbuch. There is one part of a sentence I do not really understand.

> Ich bin 17 und 1,65 Meter gross. Meine Augen sind blau, mein Haar ist braun und lang. Meine Nase ist zu klein und mein Mund zu gross. Meine Beine sind lang und meine Finger sind dick. Trotzdem finde ich, dass ich ganz in Ordnung bin.
>
> "*Meine Beine sind lang und meine Finger sind dick.*"

My question is: Does she think her *legs* are too long and fingers too big?

Comment: Zitate sollten mit der Quelle versehen werden. Name des Werks, des Autors/Verlags, Jahr, Seite.

Comment: I second @userunknown in a request for providing a source for the quotation. Other than that, could you clarify the question, please? Is it about the *too*, which is a deviation from the German sentence? Or is it about the *legs*, which are emphasized by italics in your English translation? Especially in the latter case, what alternative interpretations do you possibly see in that sentence? Knowing about these might help us understand what the difficulty is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

17 zu sein gilt nicht unbedingt als Nachteil - es käme hier auf den Kontext an. 1,65 m ist auch nicht ungewöhnlich klein, aber zu klein, um Model zu werden. In den meisten Fällen ist an braunem, langen Haar nichts auszusetzen, auch nicht an blauen Augen.

Bei Nase und Mund wird ausdrücklich darauf hingewiesen, dass sie als defizitär erlebt werden: zu klein, zu groß.

Da lange Beine eher dem Schönheitsideal entsprechen gehe ich davon aus, dass sie auch nicht als zu lang dargestellt werden sollen, sowenig wie die Augen zu blau. Dicke Finger dagegen wahrscheinlich schon.

Insgesamt scheint es mir eine Auflistung positiver, neutraler und negativer äußerer Merkmale. Statt *trotzdem* würde daher besser ein *alles in allem* in den letzten Satz gehören.

Answer (score 1):

The autor says:

> 1. I am 17 *[years old]* and 1.65 m tall.
> 2. My eyes are blue, my hair is brown and long.
> 3. My nose is too small and my mouth too big.
> 4. My legs are long and my fingers are thick. *[not big!]*
> 5. Nevertheless I think, that I am quite ok.

He/she makes only in 3 and 5 evaluative statements. The statement in 3 is negative, the statement in 5 is positive. But in 1, 2 and 4 he/she only tells facts. Neither positive nor negative.

And the autor does not say that the legs are *too* long or the fingers are *too* thick. This would be in German:

> Meine Beine sind **zu** lang und meine Finger sind **zu** dick.

Comment: While "thick' is the literal translation of "dick", "big" may be more idiomatic.

Comment: @hkBst: "big fingers" = "große Finger". Darunter verstehe ich z.B. die Finger eines Bundesliga-Handball-Torwarts. Diese Finger sind nicht nur dicker, sondern auch deutlich länger als die Finger z.B. eines sechsjährigen Mädchens. Sie haben aber für Finger ganz normale Proportionen. Bei "thick fingers" = "dicke Finger" denke ich an die Wurstfinger eines stark übergewichtigen Menschen. Also zwar deutlich dicker, aber keineswegs länger.

Comment: I understand all that, but in English "big" can often mean "dick".